# Convert .JPG or .PNG to .ICO using terminal and back

Tags: command-line, convert

Is there a command I can use to convert a `.jpg` or `.png` or other to extension to a `.ico`? If possible also to resize it to be a favicon size?

I'd also like to turn it from `.ico` to `.jpg` or `.png`.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The most useful program (suite) to manipulate image is [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) (`sudo apt install imagemagick`) and for this task you will need the [`convert`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) binary.

You will need to use something like:

```
convert -resize x16 -gravity center -crop 16x16+0+0 input.png -flatten -colors 256 -background transparent output/favicon.ico
```

Comment: It doesn't keep the transparent section of the image. The alpha channel changed to white. I don't know why.

Comment: The removal of transparency is most likely due to using the `-flatten` flag.

Answer (score 29):

This is the best command to do that from console:

`convert <your-image-here> -define icon:auto-resize=256,64,48,32,16 favicon.ico`

Hope you like it!

Comment: What does the `-define icon:auto-resize=256,64,48,32,16` do? The man pages just says that it `-define` "defines one or more image format options"

Comment: `icon:auto-resize` to automatically store multiple sizes in an ico image (*requires 256x256 input image*).

Comment: In my case, this command handled also the transparency of the source PNG better than the command in the answer off  [@systho](https://askubuntu.com/a/867568/189996).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO. The accepted answer results in a blurry image for me.

Answer (score 4):

Use this zsh function:

```
png2ico () {
    local i="${1}" o="${2:-${1:r}.ico}" s="${png2ico_size:-256}"
    convert -resize x${s} -gravity center -crop ${s}x${s}+0+0 "$i" -flatten -colors 256 -background transparent "$o"
}
```

Like so:

```
png2ico input.png
```

Comment: works also with other file format that are supported by Imagemagick, not just png